# trying to sort a txt file in c++ using a function and writing it back out to a txt file

Tags: c++, function, fstream

```
 void insertionSort (int arrtosort[], int size)
{
 int temp = arrtosort[0];
 for(int i = 1; i < size; i++)
{
    temp = arrtosort[i];
    int j = 0;
    for(j = i; j > 0; j--)
        if(temp < arrtosort[j - 1])
           arrtosort[j] = arrtosort[j - 1];
        else break;
    arrtosort[j-1] =  temp;
}
}
```

I am trying to use this sort function to sort a txt file inside of a case.

what I tried was

```
case 1:

        insertionSort(fileid,SIZE);
        ingrades.open("dataout.txt");
        for (idx=0;idx<SIZE;idx++)
        {
            int id,n_grade;
            string l_grade;
            ingrades>>id>>n_grade>>l_grade;
            for(int i=0;i<SIZE;i++)
            {
                if(fileid[i]==id)
                {
                    out.open("data.txt");
                    out<<id<<" "<<n_grade<<" "<<l_grade<<endl;
                    out.close();
                }
            }

        }
        ingrades.close();

    break;
```

I have tried different variations with this code not just writing to the txt file but to just simply display it in the console

```
14731 4
15960 6
15517 8
16638 1
34974 6
32684 4
35157 2
33904 4
23132 7
37344 3
```

These are the numbers I'm trying to sort in my program letter grades are written to it before it hits the case.
What I'm trying to do is use the function to sort the file and write it out to a txt file or simply just display on the console all help is appreciated.

another problem is that when i use the function i seem to get the same number over and over stead of all of them as though the rest were deleted and replaced by the largest number

Comment: Well you seem to repeatedly be opening `data.txt`, every time overwriting what was in there. Aside from that you really need to clean up your code, the formattings a mess and there's some unnecessary stuff in there.

Comment: ya that case was a bad example like i said i had done different variations nothing seemed to work.

Comment: Well you should probably try stepping through that with a debugger to see where the problem occurs.

Comment: Why is "arrtosort[j-1] =  temp;" outside of the for loop?

Comment: its in the else saying if it's not bigger intialize it as temp

Comment: Well, give example input & output and it would be far easier to implement our own rather than staring at this snippet of code.

Comment: there is no input the numbers are randomly generated the program takes the numbers generated then takes the first column of numbers and puts it in order i would like the console to display the order and have it organized in the txt file. i would have put the whole program but every time i do there seems to be problems with the spacing.

Comment: I have no idea what this question is asking us.  The sort seems to work fine, but your descriptions of what the problem is... make no sense.

Comment: It looks like you have an array of IDs, you sort them, then you read in grades one by one and write them to a file, completely ignoring the array of sorted IDs.  I can't figure out what your intent is at all.

Comment: the first column are ids in my program the function is supposed to organize them when i put all the arrays in a for loop to display them in the console i will get an output with all the ids the same number instead of in order (ex: it should be 1234 instead i get 2222 going all the way down)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the file, store the key value pairs into a std::map, then iterate the map from the beginning to the end writing it's contents to the file.

The trick is that std::map automaticly sorts data for you and you can even specify a comparator!

Maps are sorted based on their key.

if you want to sort only numbers here is an example from cplusplus.com

```
// sort algorithm example
#include <iostream>     // std::cout
#include <algorithm>    // std::sort
#include <vector>       // std::vector

bool myfunction (int i,int j) { return (i<j); }

struct myclass {
    bool operator() (int i,int j) { return (i<j);}
} myobject;

int main () {
    int myints[] = {32,71,12,45,26,80,53,33};
    std::vector<int> myvector (myints, myints+8);               // 32 71 12 45 26 80 53 33

    // using default comparison (operator <):
    std::sort (myvector.begin(), myvector.begin()+4);           //(12 32 45 71)26 80 53 33

    // using function as comp
    std::sort (myvector.begin()+4, myvector.end(), myfunction); // 12 32 45 71(26 33 53 80)

    // using object as comp
    std::sort (myvector.begin(), myvector.end(), myobject);     //(12 26 32 33 45 53 71 80)

    // print out content:
    std::cout << "myvector contains:";
    for (std::vector<int>::iterator it=myvector.begin(); it!=myvector.end(); ++it)
        std::cout << ' ' << *it;
    std::cout << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
myvector contains: 12 26 32 33 45 53 71 80
```

if you want more values just use `std::pair<int,int>` for the vector and create your own comparision function like in the example.

```
bool myfunction (std::pair<int,int> i,std::pair<int,int> j) { return (i.first<j.first); }
```

Comment: I've been reading up on the map template but im not to sure on how to implement it. I am still very new to c++ so im trying to figure out what it all means

Comment: if you can provide example input and expected output maybe I will be able to help a bit more.

Comment: there is no input the numbers are randomly generated (http://codepaste.net/w8q671) this is the full code with this first case im looking to have the first column of numbers organized sorry for not being specific

Comment: look at my updated answer, just push back the random numbers then do the sort.

Comment: @GamErix: [His sort seems correct to me](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=6d9fa5e29e67030a22635fe461f182d2-50d9cfc8a1d350e7409e81e87c2653ba)